# Deduce iterator type in function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, auto

I'm trying to deduce the type of an iterator in a function which is already deducing the argument's type  with a template. What I am trying to achieve is substitution for the keyword **auto** which has similar capability in *C++11* standard. Originally I had the following function:

```
    template<typename Type> bool activeExtension(Type &arr)
    {
        for (auto it=arr.begin(),
                  ite=arr.end();
                  it!=ite;
                      ++it)
        {
            if (*it != 0)
               return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This works perfectly compiling for *C++11* standard. But things have changed and I cannot use such features anymore.

I am trying the achieve same functionally without the keyword **auto**. So I thought about the templates.

So far what I tried is this:

```
    template<typename Type> bool activeExtension(Type &arr)
    {
        for (Type::iterator  it=arr.begin(),
                             ite=arr.end();
                             it!=ite;
                         ++it)
        {
            if (*it != 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How would you go to solve this?

Note:
I usually call this function with the following type,

```
template <class T>
struct Generic_t {
    typedef std::vector<T> Array;
};
```

as I have to instantiate a vector with different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `typename Type::iterator` since it's dependent-name.
Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)